# Getting Error: Antlr.Runtime.MismatchedTokenException

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

I am getting an `Error: MismatchedTokenException(-1!=104)`

The Error accure if I use that Query:

```
String hql2 = "UPDATE Buchung as b " +
              "set SERIENE = SERIENE + 1 " +
              "where ID in (SELECT rr.Buchung from Raumreservierung rr " +
              "where CHECK_IN_HAPPEND = :CheckInHappend and SERIENBOOKUID = :SerieID)";
```

Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: missing `)` at the end of query?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the alias in the where condition to

```
String hql2 = "UPDATE Buchung as b " +
    "set SERIENE = SERIENE + 1 " +
    "where ID in (SELECT rr.Buchung from Raumreservierung rr " +
    "where rr.CHECK_IN_HAPPEND = :CheckInHappend and rr.SERIENBOOKUID = :SerieID)";
```